# Is this a misuse of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm making the shift towards smart pointers, and I'm trying to make sure I use them properly. There are plenty of questions that cover when to use each one, but I wasn't able to find a question specifically about getters.

I have a class that owns a pointer, and I want other classes to be able to access that pointer  (Refactoring legacy code in steps). I wanted to give the class a unique_ptr because it will only own that object, but they can't be copied. Should I be returning a reference to the unique_ptr, or just using a shared_ptr?

```
class B
{
 public:
    doAction() {};
};

class A
{
 private:
    std::unqiue_ptr<B> pointer;

 public:
    std::unique_ptr<B>& GetPointer()
    {
        return pointer;
    }

};

a.GetPointer()->doAction();
```

Comment: Personally I use raw pointers or references for non-owning access.  (Use a pointer if the value is allowed to be null; use a reference otherwise)

Comment: This would allow the caller to do `a.GetPointer().reset();` Might not be quite what you had in mind. It might be best to have `GetPointer()` return a raw pointer instead, as in `return pointer.get();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the other class needs to store the pointer and potentially lives longer than your class A, use a `shared_ptr`.

If not, and your `B` object should be destructed on destruction of A, this is a perfectly valid use of a `unique_ptr`.

As pointed out in the comments, this only holds true if other classes are also allowed to change your pointer. If not, return a raw pointer.

The difference between both is not about who has access to the class, but about who is responsible for the destruction of the referenced object.

Answer (score 5):

If the code only needs access to a `B` object through the unique_ptr then you're better off just returning the raw pointer with `pointer.get();`. Remember, raw pointers aren't bad, owning raw pointers are.

Comment: Or return a reference, which also signals that no "ownership" is returned: `B& GetBReference() { return *pointer; }`

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be returning a reference to the unique_ptr, or just using a shared_ptr?

It depends.

Does something else need to own the pointer? If yes, then use shared ownership. If you don't need shared ownership, then `A` can be the sole owner and therefore `unique_ptr` is appropriate.

But in that case, I would instead return a reference (or a raw pointer, if the `unique_ptr` may be null) to the object, not the `unique_ptr`. That encapsulates the control of the ownership so that it can only be changed within the member functions. If you have a function that returns a reference to the `unique_ptr`, then you have no encapsulation and you might as well have made the `unique_ptr` public in the first place in the name of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Return a raw pointer, or a reference to the object being pointed to. When an object holds a `std::unique_ptr` this indicates ownership. Meaning, the object holding the pointer will allocate and also delete the allocated resources when it so pleases.

For example:

```
class Car {
public:
  Engine* getEngine() const { return engine_.get(); }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Engine> engine_;
}
```

You may ask for the car's possibly available engine, you should always assume that it might not be there but you should definitely never deallocate it, it's not yours, it's owned by the car.